# add value to emply field powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a doc lib Test and column employee. I want to run powershell which check if any column (employee) has empty value then update the field value with "AAA". Under document library we have document sets and for each doc sets we have properties(employee) which is field(employee) in library. now need to update that property.
How to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> **Try with this?**

```
    $web = Get-SPWeb http://YourServer/
    $list = $web.Lists["Test"]
    foreach ($item in $list.Items)
    {
      if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($item["employee"]))
      {
        $item["employee"] = "AAA";
        $item.Update();
       }
    }
    $web.Dispose()
```

Comment: there is little correction in question. Under document library we have document sets and for each doc sets we have properties which is field in library. now need to update that property. does it still work?